# The Source of PtIJ

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy

I was curious why PTIJ exists on this forum. How did it get started here and why does it prevail?

Comment: The Q&A at http://Judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/772 tells the story.

Comment: @IsaacMoses That's an answer, and a dupe.